# how to parse arguments object in c++ v8

Tags: c++, v8

I want to have access in javascript to my c++ function with google v8 engine and return result according arguments giving in my javascript function.

My javascript function is as follow:

```
var result = MyFc(
                 {
                  'stringData':'abc',
                  'numberData':123,
                  'arrData':[1,2,3],
                  'objData':{'a':true,'b':false,'c':true},
                  'callback':function(){}
                 }
);
```

I used

```
global->Set(v8::String::New("myFc"), v8::FunctionTemplate::New(MyFc));

v8::Handle<v8::Value> MyFc(const v8::Arguments& args) {
  obj = args[0]->...
  if( obj->stringData != 'abc' ){
      //....
  }
  if( obj->numberData != 123 ){
      //....
  }
  if( obj->arrData[2] != 3 ){
      //....
  }
  if( obj->objData->b == false ){
      //....
  }
  if( obj->callback !='abc' ){
      //....
  }
}
```

My question is how to parse arguments object in c++ v8? I want to access to all key values of the object in arguments, values can be an number, string, array, anonymous function or object.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use type checking methods of `v8::Value` (`IsBoolean()`, `IsArray()`, `IsObject()` etc) and  then `v8::Handle<T>::Cast(v8::Handle<S>)` to cast `args[i]` values to corresponding types.

Your code should look like this:

```
if (args[0]->IsArray()) {
    Handle<Array> array = Handle<Array>::Cast(arg[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < array->Length(); i++) {
       //...
    }
}
if (args[1]->IsObject()) {
    Handle<Object> object = Handle<Object>::Cast(args[i]);
    Handle<Value> fieldValue = object->Get(String::New("a"));
    Handle<Value> callback = object->Get(String::New("callback"));
    if (callback->IsFunction()) {
        Handle<Function> fn = Handle<Function>::Cast(callback);
    }
}
```

Comment: How to check a callback function?

Comment: Modified example to include check whether "callback" is a function.

Comment: FWIW, This solution didn't work for me, but the one from the following question did http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707167/how-to-convert-v8-value-to-array

Comment: is it a problem if one of the object keys aren't there? Does it automatically check for that or should we do a `Object->Has("key")` type of check?

Answer (score 0):

**Attention**:

> This method only **works up to Node JS version 0.8**. **As of August 19,
>   2013 [v8 juice project](https://code.google.com/p/v8-juice/) is being abandoned** due to the degree of incompatible
>   changes in the core v8 made during the first half of of 2013.
>
> Working on updating [the code aponxi/npm-execxi](https://github.com/aponxi/npm-execxi/) to interpret JavaScript variables in C++
>   without using cvv8 library.

---

This is how I handle arguments. I hope this helps someone!

Full script is from [execxi.cpp](https://github.com/aponxi/npm-execxi/blob/master/execxi.cpp) at [aponxi/npm-execxi](https://github.com/aponxi/npm-execxi/)

Note: I'm using [v8::juice](http://code.google.com/p/v8-juice/wiki/ConvertingTypes) to convert from JS to C++

```
#include <node/node.h>
#include <v8.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdio>

#include <cvv8/convert.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <set>
namespace cv = cvv8;
using namespace v8;

Handle<Value> executeArray(const Arguments& args) {
    HandleScope scope;

// here I define default options in c++
// later we will parse options that come from js
// and convert values to C++ values, and replace
// these default options with the one provided
// for the sace of example I just copy pasted one
// option here:

    // OPTIONS
    /////////////////////

    //
    // Chained (bool)
    //   If a command doesn't exit with 0 then we won't run the next command
    //   default: true
    bool Chained = true;

// there is code here that checks if first arguments is passed
// and handles that argument
// the second argument is options, as if 
// "myfunction("arg1", {chained: false})"
// comes from javascript.
// This part below checks if there are two arguments
// since passing options is totally optional.
// we begin by checking if two arguments are passed:

if (args.Length() == 2)
    {
      if (args[1]->IsObject())
      {
        // you must be passing options...
        // it must be an object


        Handle<Object> opt = Handle<Object>::Cast(args[1]);

        if (opt->Has(String::New("chained"))) {
          // you passed chained option
          if ((opt->Get(String::New("chained"))->IsBoolean())){
            // the chained option must be bool
            Handle<Value> _chained = opt->Get(String::New("chained"));
            Chained = cv::CastFromJS<bool>(_chained);

          } else {
            // chained is not bool, throw error
            ThrowException(Exception::TypeError(String::New("not bool")));
            return scope.Close(Undefined());
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```