# How to convert v8 Value to Array

Tags: javascript, c++, v8

I'm writing a c++ extension to v8, and want to pass an Array object into it. I see the incoming argument can be tested by IsArray(), but there isn't a ToArray().

How do you get access to its Length, and request elements by numeric index?

```
Handle<Value> MyExtension(const Arguments& args)
{
    Handle<Value> v = args[0];
    if(v->IsArray())
    {
        // convert to array, find its length, and access its members by index... ?
    }
...
}
```

Must be missing something obvious here. Object can return all its properties, but that's not quite what I was hoping for. Is there a way to get it as an Arrray?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: This was a while ago, but shouldn't `args[0]->ToObject.As<Array>();` do the trick?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a way to convert or cast to Array. Maybe there's a way. But I found by doing `object->IsArray()`, `object->get("length")->Uint32Value()`, and `object->get(int)`, I could just walk the array.

```
v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj;
// ... init obj from arguments or wherever ...

int length = 0;
if(obj->IsArray())
{
    length = obj->Get(v8::String::New("length"))->ToObject()->Uint32Value();
}

for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    v8::Local<v8::Value> element = obj->Get(i);
    // do something with element
}
```

Answer (score 14):

You should use `Cast` method of a handle to cast it to a different type:

```
v8::Handle<v8::Array> array = v8::Handle<v8::Array>::Cast(v);
```

Comment: This seems so close! But I get a cast error: error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'v8::Value *' to 'v8::Object *volatile '

I'm wondering now if I just have to read the .length property myself...

Comment: this is very strange. I know that the line above *must* compile just fine if `v` is `Handle<Value>` because this is how `Cast` is intended to be used. Where does compilation error point to? Can you post your source?

Answer (score 5):

i was able to get things working like this, its just a variation of the answer Vyacheslav Egorov gave

```
Local<Array> arr= Local<Array>::Cast(args[0]);
printf("size %d\n",arr->Length());
Local<Value> item = arr->Get(0);
```

Answer (score 3):

The below is my succeeded code

```
v8::Handle<v8::Value> obj(args[0]);

 if(obj->IsArray()){

     v8::Local<v8::Array> arr= v8::Local<v8::Array>::Cast(args[0]);
     v8::String::Utf8Value key(arr->Get(0));
     v8::String::Utf8Value value(arr->Get(1));

 }
```