# How to convert an V8 Array to std::vector<std::string>?

Tags: c++, node.js, v8

I am using [Nan](https://github.com/nodejs/nan) and I am trying to convert an array of strings into `std::vector<std::string>`. The question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707167/how-to-convert-v8-value-to-array) and most answers refer to the snippet below.

Unfortunately the compiler complains about `Get` not being a member of `v8::Array` (see error below).

```cpp
  std::vector<std::string> args;
  v8::Local<v8::Array> array = v8::Local<v8::Array>::Cast(info[1]);
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < array->Length(); i++) {
    auto val = array->Get(i);
    args.push_back(std::string(*String::Utf8Value(val)));
  }
```

Error:

```
error: no matching member function for call to 'Get'
    auto val = array->Get(i);
```

I have installed the latest version of **nan** and I am using Node `14.18.1`.

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "nan": "^2.15.0"
```

Can anyone help out?

Comment: I tried that already, but no success ```no member named 'Get' in 'v8::Local<v8::Array>'; did you mean to use '->' instead of '.'?```

Comment: The question you refer to is for an older version of v8. I linked you to a question for the more modern api.